# How to deal with complex json data in vb.net webservice

Tags: vb.net, rest

I am (trying) to create a RestApi in VB.net and have hit a dead end when it comes to posting data to my endpoint. If i use a simple json file post it via postman and bind it to my data class it is fine but once the Data class becomes more complex it no longer works. By that i mean a class like below works

```
<First>
<Last>
<AddressLine1>
<City>
<State>
```

but

```
<UserInfo>
   <Name>
      <First>
      <Last>
   </Name>
   <Address>
      <AddressLine1>
      <City>
      <State>
   </Address>
</UserInfo>
```

does not. So here are my 2 question 
A) Is there a way to have the build in Parser handle more complex data classes like my above since this doesnt work

```
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As User_Info) As String
 If ModelState.IsValid Then
   Console.Write(value.address.CITY)
   Return "OK"
 Else
   Return "Error"
 End If
End Function
```

b) what is the alternate way to access the json posted in body so i can manually
assign the values to my complex data class ?

Comment: You may want to look into reading in `xml` data, as that's what you have, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is not JSON. It's very easy if you just use the built-in functionality.

Here is what your class would look like

```
<DataContract()>
Class UserInfo
    <DataMember>
    Public Name As New Name
    <DataMember>
    Public Address As New Address
End Class

<DataContract()>
Class Name
    <DataMember>
    Public First As String
    <DataMember>
    Public Last As String
End Class

<DataContract()>
Class Address
    <DataMember>
    Public AddressLine1 As String
    <DataMember>
    Public City As String
    <DataMember>
    Public State As String
End Class
```

Here's an example that save to JSON and loads it back.

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
    Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

    Dim ui As New UserInfo

    ' Initialize
    ui.Name.First = "f"
    ui.Name.Last = "l"
    ui.Address.AddressLine1 = "a"
    ui.Address.City = "c"
    ui.Address.State = "s"

    ' Write to stream
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream
    Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(UserInfo))

    ser.WriteObject(stream, ui)

    ' Show data
    stream.Position = 0
    Dim sr = New StreamReader(stream)
    Dim jsonData As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(jsonData)

    ' Bring it back
    Dim ui2 As UserInfo
    stream.Position = 0
    ui2 = ser.ReadObject(stream)

    Console.WriteLine(ui.Name.First)
    Console.WriteLine(ui.Name.Last)
    Console.WriteLine(ui.Address.AddressLine1)
    Console.WriteLine(ui.Address.City)
    Console.WriteLine(ui.Address.State)
```

This would be the JSON generated

```
{
  "Address":
  {
    "AddressLine1":"a",
    "City":"c",
    "State":"s"
  },
  "Name":
  {
    "First":"f",
    "Last":"l"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I maybe was a bit unclear, the data was only a representation of what my data class looks like . I was trying to avoid to put the whole data class code on the post. Also my problem is not how to create a json but how to take a json in a webservice and populate a dataclass. It works if it’s simple a collection of fields but doesn’t once it gets more complicated with sub nodes etc.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder I just gave you an example on how to load a json with "sub-node" like your  sample.

Comment: I dont want to generate a json, i have a RestApi which i post a json doc too. The problem i am having is that if i specify my data class it fails to load it correctly. It works fine for simple doc but not for a more complex

Comment: @ConfusedCoder you should post the JSON that isn't loading. I used a JSON with the same structure that you put in your question and it's loading fine.